# Why is overseas 3G so expensive?

Tags: internet, 3g

The question is: why is overseas 3G access so expensive?

I normally live in UK and while travelling abroad, noticed that data rates are just astronomical. Is there a technical reason for this or is it a purely economical issue? Is it really justified or just phone companies being "greedy" and overcharging tourists just because they can?

I am not sure if this is the right website of Stack Exchange to ask the question, but seems to be the closest match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a matter of both, although your provider will have to pay/lease for you to use the overseas' network.

Some network providers do offer an overseas/abroad package, check the website for yours and see what you can find.